# ContextMenu initiated from GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, contextmenu

Just wondering if anyone can help with this - I'm learning and unable to figure it out......

If I register a GridView object with a Context Menu as follows:

```
registerForContextMenu(gridview);
```

How can I determine which View object/square in the Grid the menu was initiated from?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onContextItemSelected()` method, you can get the index of the item on the Grid by using:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
int index = info.position;
```

Then use this **index** for everything you want :)

Comment: Thank you so much - it works! I have tried 3 posts, and have been trying to figure it out since Saturday! thank you so much